# PHP Stomp: Reading all messages in a queue

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I need to find a specific message within an ActiveMQ queue using PHP and remove it.

AFAIK the only way to do so is to read all messages that are currently queued and ACK the one message I'm interested in. ([The example in the PHP manual for Stomp::ack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stomp.ack.php) does more or less the same thing, they don't read all messages, but only ACK the one that matches).

So, I wrote this code (this is only the relevant part, obviously):

```
class StompController {

    private $con;

    public function __construct($stompSettings) {
        try {
            $this->con = new Stomp($stompSettings['scheme']."://".$stompSettings['host'].":".$stompSettings['port']);
            $this->con->connect();
            $this->con->setReadTimeout(5);
        } catch(StompException $e) {
            die('Connection failed:' .$e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->con->disconnect();
    }

    public function ackMessageAsRead($recipient,$message) {
        if($this->con->isConnected()) {
            //Subscribe to the recipient user's message queue.
            $this->con->subscribe("/queue/".$recipient);
            //Read all messages currently in the queue (but only ACK the one we're interested in).
            while($this->con->hasFrameToRead()) {
                $msg = $this->con->readFrame();
                if($msg != null && $msg != false) {
                    //This is the message we are currently reading, ACK it to AMQ and be done with it.
                    if($msg->body == $message) {
                        $this->con->ack($msg);
                    }
                } 
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

According to my logic, this should work.
While running the code only **one *random*** message is being read though, despite checking for more frames.

The next frame seems only to be prepared when the frame we're currently reading has been ACK'ed. (When I manually ACK all messages the `while` loop works as intended, all messages are processed.

Does anyone know how to get the full set of messages from the queue, without ACK'ing all of them? I can ACK all of them and put the ones I wasn't interested in back into the queue afterwards, but this already inefficient way to find a single message gets a whole lot more inefficient that way.

Comment: Are you setting activemq.prefetchSize to any value? If activemq.prefetchSize is 1, broker will wait for the ack of the message before it sends the next message.

Comment: @Buchi That sounds like exactly the thing I'm looking for! I'll check if changing that will do me any good when I'm back at the office tomorrow, but this pretty much sounds like the issue.

Comment: @Buchi That was the problem indeed, a higher `activemq.prefetchSize` header while subscribing to the queue did fetch the remaining messages. Unfortunately frames after the first one are incorrectly terminated (or incorrectly parsed by the PHP Stomp client, I'm guessing the latter) by a "�" char instead of `\x00`, which collates all remaining messages in the body field of the second message. I think I'm sticking with my original plan for now: feed messages back to the queue. Care to transform your comment into an answer so I can accept it as correct anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an issue due to setting `activemq.prefetchSize` to 1. ActiveMQ uses a prefetch size on how many messages can be dispatched to a consumer at any point in time. Once the prefetch size is reached, no more messages are dispatched to the consumer until the consumer starts sending back acknowledgements. Increasing the prefetch size should fix your issue to my best knowledge.

Please read http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html for more details on prefetch limit.